# Looking for an article by Williams called "Brownian motion and diffusions as Markov processes"

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

As title says,

I am looking for an article by D.Williams called "Brownian motion and diffusions as Markov processes".

It was mentioned in the preface of his first edition of Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales.

Comment: I mean this as nicely as possible: have you Googled it? I believe I found it immediately.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery for free? I wasnt able to access it.

Comment: I didn't check, but it's either freely available, or it's unethical for me or anyone else to give you a copy.

Comment: Copyright laws and ethics are different things (I am sure this is not my opinion only - https://gowers.wordpress.com/category/elsevier/). Since I am not aware of a MSE policy in favour or against SciHub, I am acting single-handed and letting the answer stay for the time being. I need to perform an investigation about the general consensus on the matter.

Comment: I totally agree that something is deeply wrong with the state of publishing. But, the correct response to that doesn't feel to me like embracing gray market reprint sites. Even if that is the correct response, I'd at the very least not like to see MSE become a site where discussions like this are common. (I'm fine with your moderation decision, at any rate.)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have to admit that I had some second-thoughts about posting the link. My personal view is that sci-hub is fully ethical (and a tool I use very frequently). That said, if Stack policy is against this practice, obviously I erred by posting it here and I will delete my answer. And do excuse me if I created a dilemma for a new, but in many ways distinguished moderator of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

"[Brownian Motions and Diffusions as Markov Processes](https://sci-hub.cc/http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/blms/6.3.257/abstract)"

Comment: thanks, I could not find it via my university for some reason.

Comment: @user1 My pleasure. It does seem a bit rare so (If you want, you can like/accept the answer..).

Comment: There is a few min. waiting time until it possible to accept :)

Comment: @user1 I know! :-) Hope you find the article useful!